# Why JPA takes time for transition from close stmt to next Prepare stmt

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, prepared-statement

I have JPA statement that on execution performs simple query .

I checked the logs,
it is executing in acceptable time but for performing the next statement it takes time to prepare the next statement

here are the logs

```
2021-03-01T12:35:42.008614Z    84 Prepare   SELECT * from table where id=?
2021-03-01T12:35:42.008810Z    84 Execute   SELECT * from table where id=4
2021-03-01T12:35:42.012826Z    84 Close stmt    
2021-03-01T12:35:42.033090Z    84 Prepare   SELECT * from table where id=?
2021-03-01T12:35:42.033279Z    84 Execute   SELECT * from table where id=5
2021-03-01T12:35:42.033860Z    84 Close stmt    
2021-03-01T12:35:42.054576Z    84 Prepare   SELECT * from table where id=?
2021-03-01T12:35:42.054792Z    84 Execute   SELECT * from table where id=6
2021-03-01T12:35:42.055372Z    84 Close stmt
```

the time difference may not seem much but this statement is going to be executed for around 1200+ times, so the final delay is just too much

is there any way that the transition time (time between close statement and next prepare statement) can be reduced?

There are no statements or lines of code in between to cause any time delay, it is single statement in the loop

:Update->

I managed to reduce the transition time by enabling `CachePrepStmt` property in application.yml file

so the new transition time is around 0.1 ms but now the execution time is 20ms

how can it happen , any ideas?

Here are the new log statements

```
    
2021-03-02T06:20:51.249367Z    59 Execute   SELECT * from table where id=5
2021-03-02T06:20:51.269273Z    59 Reset stmt    
2021-03-02T06:20:51.269385Z    59 Execute   SELECT * from table where id=6
2021-03-02T06:20:51.289372Z    59 Reset stmt    
2021-03-02T06:20:51.289512Z    59 Execute   SELECT * from table where id=7
2021-03-02T06:20:51.308678Z    59 Reset stmt    
2021-03-02T06:20:51.308812Z    59 Execute   SELECT * from table where id=8
2021-03-02T06:20:51.328953Z    59 Reset stmt    
2021-03-02T06:20:51.329123Z    59 Execute   SELECT * from table where id=9
2021-03-02T06:20:51.348447Z    59 Reset stmt
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, looks like you just use prepared statement. In this case you don't need JPA,it is enough to involve JDBC PreparedStatement.

Second, you could reduce work using `in' predicate like that:

```
SELECT * from table where id in (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

That results in a fast enough single select in case `id' is a primary key or indexed field. But do not forget to check length of you query to be reasonable.

Another option is to select a range of ids

```
SELECT * from table where id between 4 and 9
```

Then filter result at the client as you need, just skip unnesessary ids.

Comment: Hi, @S.Kadakov , I updated the question, can you help me figure out how the execution time is increased now? - Thanks

Comment: at the point it seems that you manage to reset your prepared statement (seting new value resets that), but you still don't reduce a number of queries. try to reduce that, so you lower total execution time.

Comment: I cannot reduce the number of queries because it is being used for each and every execution, i checked the server logs, it doesn't take any significant time to set the values obtained from above execution(around 0.001ms) , my main problem lies with reducing the execution time

Comment: is it some kind of cachhing?

Comment: yes, i set ```cachePrepStmts: true``` by this the transition time is reduced significantly by somehow the execution time in logs is increased but when i used ```explain analyze``` on mysql query it is showing that the execution time is only about 0.4-1ms
I can't figure out where the remaining time is goiing

Comment: in this case you do not need to populate cache manually. JPA specification already support  cahing: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/cache_usaged

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229387/discussion-between-deviprasad-sharma-and-s-kadakov).